# xpath/css href not printing

Tags: css, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I am trying to print the href of a html doc, however I am not able to do so.

```
newurl = 'http://www.heroesfire.com/hots/guide/the-many-ways-of-abathur-1194'
    buildpage = Nokogiri::HTML(open(newurl))
        #puts buildpage
        thistext = buildpage.css("div#wrap div#site-content.self-clear div#guide.view-guide div.col-l div.tab-contents.box div.guide-tab div.chapter-text div.text table.bbcode_columns tbody tr td.bbcode_column a").each do |href|
          puts href['href']
        end
```

I am expecting to see '/hots/wiki/talents/pressurized-glands'

I was able to get something similar to work earlier in my script, but I am having zero luck with this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We expect the minimal HTML in the question itself. We also expect that your code is valid and able to be run. I'd also recommend using proper indentation. That will help you and others.

Comment: My code is valid and runs, but the HTML in question is extremely large. Should I still post it?

Comment: As "[mcve]" says, you should supply the *minimal* data necessary to demonstrate the problem in the question itself. Strip everything from the HTML not necessary to demonstrate your question. Anything else wastes our time as we try to help. Your sample code is *NOT* syntactically correct. Look at your definition of `newurl`; It generates a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invariably, the longer the Node selector, the less likely it will work correctly, especially if you're dealing with HTML you don't control.

Reduce it to find way-points, places that help you drill down instead of trying to define each step.

You're also relying on `tbody` in the selector. When we see that, the odds are good that it's not in the original HTML source but instead was injected by your browser. Selectors like that smell of using a browser and an inspector to locate a particular item in the page, but the resulting path won't work if the HTML doesn't actually contain `tbody`. Browsers do a lot of fix-up in an attempt to present something useful, including adding tags. So be careful when you see `tbody` and confirm it actually exists. In your case, it does, but the concern still exists when navigating through a document.

A simple example of simplifying the path is:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
  <div id="foo">
    <div id="bar">
      <p>text1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="baz">
      <p>text2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

doc.at('body div#foo div#bar p').text # => "text1"
```

Can be written more easily, while still accomplishing the same thing, using:

```
doc.at('#bar p').text # => "text1"
```

or perhaps one of these:

```
doc.at('#foo div p').text # => "text1"
doc.search('#foo div p').first.text # => "text1"
```

All scraping requires at least some advance knowledge of the target page's structure, so, while you're nosing around, take note of the important layout tags. `id` parameters are especially useful, followed by `class` and/or unique patterns of tags not replicated elsewhere in the document. Those make it easy to reduce the selector. Sometimes we have to step into the document incrementally like I did using `first` or one of the "sibling" methods after locating a particular node, but using a long selector rarely is needed.